# FirebaseException ([core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

We aren't sure why, but last night our app built and ran fine, we haven't changed anything and this morning running gives the above error.

This is how our we are init firebase

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)? Pay attention to step #4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const firebaseConfig = {
//Please add the relevant values below
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
    };
   
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

You can find these info in firebase console

Comment: We have never added this we have the Google-Info.plist

Comment: Are you running it on ios? For Android you would need googleservices.json

Comment: iOS we have had it working seamlessly for 2 years. Now this morning we are getting this issue

Comment: Understood but please try my suggestion and it will work

Comment: Tried above 100% still gives same error

Comment: Delete Pods folder, delete Podfile.lock and .symlinks folder. Then try to build it again

Comment: this doesn't seem like an answer to something that was working less than 20 hours to just start randomly deleting directories

Comment: These are temp folders, it will recreate it if you build it again. There might be a problem if you had opened another project and the pods got corrupted. 

Delete only the following
Pods folder
Podfile.lock
.symlinks

If you are concerned about the safety of the project please take a backup. But I do this most of the times.